# Can I make a application frontend for smartphones using Python?

Tags: python, frontend, apt

I've done a little predictive program with Python and I would like to transform it in an application for smartphones. Can I accomplish it with Python itself, or should I use another language? If yes, what APIs would you recommend for that?

Thanks

Comment: "Smartphone Python app" or "Smartphone python framework" in Google would be great places to start

Comment: Sorry for making the question! I’ve done it before but it gave me to many confusing results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).

Comment: It’s great! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! If this fully answers your question, make sure to mark it as accepted!

Comment: I’ll do it. But I have to wait for 5 minutes before.